# Docker image deploys locally but fails on Google Cloud Run

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-run

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# Use lightweight Python image
FROM python:3.9-slim

ARG DOCKER_ENV

# PYTHONFAULTHANDLER=1 - Display trace if a sefault occurs.
# PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 - Allow statements and log messages to immediately appear in the Knative logs
# PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off - Disable pip cache for smaller Docker images.
# PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=on - Ignore pip new version warning.
# PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100 - Give pip longer than the 15 second timeout. 
ENV DOCKER_ENV=${DOCKER_ENV} \
  PYTHONFAULTHANDLER=1 \
  PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
  PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off \
  PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=on \
  PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100

# Install poetry 
RUN pip install

# Set working directory in container to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy only dependency requirements to container to cache them in docker layer
COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml /app/

# Don't need virtualenv because environment is already isolated in a container
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false

# Install production dependencies 
RUN poetry install --no-dev --no-ansi

# Copy app into container 
COPY . /app

# Run server
CMD [ "poetry", "run" , "python", "api.py"]
```

I can build and deploy this locally no problem and the server starts. However, when I deploy to Cloud Run, I get the following error and the container fails:

```
Creating virtualenv indie-9TtSrW0h-py3.9 in /home/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs
File "/app/api.py", line 6, in <module>
    import jwt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jwt'
```

Does anybody have any idea why this successfully works locally but is missing a dependency in Cloud Run? One weird thing is that I explicitly telling docker to NOT use a virtual environment in the Dockerfile. This works when I run the image locally, but on Google Cloud it insists on building a virtual environment anyways. Is there some sort of incompatibility with Google Cloud Run's version of Docker and poetry that I'm missing here?

Comment: Specify the dependencies in the file **requirements.txt**.

Comment: Did you try your container is another environment? Compute Engine, ou Cloud Shell for example?

Comment: @crazysnake99 Did you solve this? I'm having exactly this issue as well.

Comment: @crazysnake99 I tried giving in and setting the `poetry config virtualenvs.create` from `false` to `true`, but it didn't help.

Comment: @JohnHanley Why would he specify requirements in `requirements.txt`? Poetry installs requirements to the container the same way the `pip` would. It seems like for some reason on **Cloud Run** the `CMD` command from `Dockerfile` is isolated, being rin in a different context than the rest of the commands.

Answer (score 3):

We had a similar problem - build succeeded but Cloud Run service start failed with a module not found, though with a slightly different config.

In our case, we didn't set `virtualenvs.create`.

This is one solution to the problem - set [`virtualenvs.in-project true`](https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#virtualenvsin-project)

```sh
# Create virtualenv at .venv in the project instead of ~/.cache/
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true
# Install production dependencies 
RUN poetry install --no-dev --no-ansi
```

Another solution is to explicitly [set the virtualenv path](https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#virtualenvsin-project), so it doesn't rely on `$HOME`, eg:

```sh
# Create virtualenv at /venv in the project instead of ~/.cache/
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.path /venv
# Install production dependencies 
RUN poetry install --no-dev --no-ansi
```

Either way beware that poetry will use the virtualenv at ./.venv if it sees it, so ensure you have `.venv/` in `.dockerignore`.

I'm pretty sure this is because of [this issue](https://chanind.github.io/2021/09/27/cloud-run-home-env-change.html) which is causing Cloud Run to set `$HOME=home` if the container user is `root`.

According to this HN comment this is a bug and will be fixed:
https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=28678152 , see also ["google cloud run" changes HOME to /home for CMD where RUN uses /root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62276734/google-cloud-run-changes-home-to-home-for-cmd-where-run-uses-root)

I think the more general solution to this issue is set [`USER`](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#user) so `poetry install` isn't running as root.

Comment: Hi, I face the same problem. Can you help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78046586/building-docker-image-fails-on-google-cloud-build-but-works-locally/78055653#78055653

Answer (score 1):

It seems like for some reason Cloud Run runs `CMD` command in an isolated context from the rest of your `Dockerfile`. That's why `poetry` thinks that it should create a new virtualenv.

### Workaround

> (It works for me at 21.11.2021)

Instead of

```
CMD [ "poetry", "run" , "python", "api.py"]
```

Use:

```
CMD ["python", "api.py"]
```

It should work as your dependencies are already installed without virtualenv, so you don't need `poetry` at this point anymore.

Comment: Hello, Can you suggest me edits to make here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78046586/building-docker-image-fails-on-google-cloud-build-but-works-locally/78055653#78055653